# SQL*Plus Code total and calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle

Show customer first name, customer e-mail address, product name, and total units (calculated by adding units in stock to units on order), but only for orders placed on or before 15 March 2015.  Create an alias for the calculated column (“Total Units”) and sort by product name.

Tables to implement on:

- product.. parent of orderLine
- customer.. Parent of order
- order.. parent of orderLine
- OrderLine.. child of order & product
- Supplier.. Parent of product

Comment: Can you supply proper DDLs for the tables? Also - what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is what I tried so far. I'm no so sure what to add more.. Hope this answers your questions to me..

SELECT customerFirstName, customerEmail, productName, 
quantity*unitPrice AS “Total Price”
FROM orderLine ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out the use of correlated sub queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html):

This is MySQL but it can be applied to what you may need.

Maybe some more details on your tables & data would help us, we're making assumptions on joins and table structure. First determine the relationship on how in stock and on order can be joined than join that with the customer info...not your exact solution but something like this:

```
SELECT T1.FIRST_NAME, T1.EMAIL, SUB1.TOTAL_UNITS
FROM CUSTOMER T1
/* CORRELATED SUB QUERY TO GROUP ORDER INFO */
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT (T1.INSTOCK + T2.ON_ORDER) AS TOTAL_UNITS
  FROM ORDER T1
  LEFT JOIN PROUDCT T2 ON T1.CUST_ID = T2.CUST_ID
  WHERE T1.INSTOCK = TRUE AND T2.ON_ORDER
) AS SUB1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
SELECT customerFirstName, customerEmail, productName, (quantity*unitPrice) AS 'Total Price' FROM orderLine WHERE orderDate <= TO_DATE(‘2015-03-15’,’yyyy-mm-dd’) order by productName
```

Comment: Thank you..This is my final code, could you please check it for me?

SELECT customerFirstName, customerEmail, productName, (quantity*unitPrice) AS 'Total Units' 
FROM orderLine 
WHERE orderDate <= TO_DATE(‘2015-03-15’,’yyyy-mm-dd’)
ORDER BY productName

Comment: I updated to include Date. Sorry about that. Let me know if that works.

Comment: `AS 'Total Price'` is invalid SQL. Single quotes are for string literals. Identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes. Also Oracle doesn't have a `datediff` function.

Comment: Well the OPs comment to my answer should work as posted. According to the oracle documentation.

Comment: Also, from what I have read, single quotes should be used for column aliasing when a space is needed.

Comment: In SQL*Plus we use single quotes for Aliases..
I will try this and let you know, thanks again..